# How to test the catch block code in Spock unit test Grails

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, spock

Hi i am having my controller action like this and i want to test the catch block of my action tst with the help of Spock Controllers Unit test in Grails

```
class AbcController{
       def tst(Long id) {
       Abc abc =  Abc.get(id)
          try{
            ................
            println "Try block"
            ..................
          }
          catch(DataIntegrityViolationException e){
            ........
            println "Catch block"
            ........
          }
      }    
}
```

My test case is like.

```
@TestFor(AbcController)
@Mock([Abc])
class AbcControllerSpec extends Specification {
  void 'Test action catch block'() {
    setup:
      params.id = 1
    when:
      controller.tst()
    then:
      thrown DataIntegrityViolationException
    expect:
      1==1
  }
}
```

But the Catch block code is not executing at all please help me in doing so.

Comment: maybe i don't understand what you are after, but throwN means, that an exception has to be thrown to make the test pass.  it does not throw one for you. if you want to make sure, that the try{} block there fails, then extract it into a separate method, set it up to fail and test this. if you really need to know if an exception was thrown AND catched within the body of a method, i'd guess, that gradle has no tool for that.  you could try mocking the exception class itself and see if it got constructed.

Comment: @cfrick:  I am trying to test the catch block of the code and i am unable to create a Exception from my test case and i can't make any change to controller code. So if you can provide some code implementation then it will be beneficial for  everyone who face issues like this with Spock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to throw an exception in your test case. You could something like this (not tested):

```
@TestFor(AbcController)
@Mock([Abc])
class AbcControllerSpec extends Specification {
  void 'Test action catch block'() {
    setup:
      this.metaClass.println = { Object value ->
         throw new DataIntegrityViolationException()
      }
    and:
      params.id = 1
    when:
      controller.tst()
    then:
      DataIntegrityViolationException dive = thrown()
  }
}
```

Comment: Garcia: tried you solution but getting - Expected exception org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException, but no exception was thrown

Comment: You have to force an exception to test the case. In the example I posted, I override the method println to throw an exception but if in your code you don't have any println, it won't throw any exception. You would need to override any method used in the try/catch block to throw an exception, no matter if it is the println one or another.

Comment: Garcia: I have tried your solution as it is to check the working but it is giving exception please refer my above comment.

Comment: I read your comment. What I am trying to explain is that the test case I wrote would only be helpful if you had a strictly identical method you wrote in the original question, even with the parte println "Try block". It would be nice if you could even provide the real code and not just a modified example.

Comment: i have executed your test case with my Q controller code it is giving : Expected exception org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException, but no exception was thrown

Comment: Can you please write your Q controller?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72922/discussion-between-shashank-gupta40-and-fran-garcia).

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing `DataIntegrityViolationException` it means you must be inserting and updating some record in the `try` block.

To test `catch` block you need a test case which violates one of the DB constraints while inserting or updating the record.

For e.g. inserting record with duplicate primary key.

Comment: @Husssain you are correct. but in the code i am just updating the Boolean  field of the object and then saving it but the Q is how to achive that through spock test case.

Comment: You have to force an exception with something like I posted in the previous comment.